# Subtract only if amount was added

Tags: jquery

I am getting a base price via ajax and then I have two (bootstrap) radio buttons to let the user add extras which says 'Yes' and 'No'. So right now, when I'm getting the base price and click on 'No' on one of the radio buttons, it subtracts from the base price rather than keep the price same.

Case 1: When the user clicks 'Yes', extra price is added to the base price and when the user changes mind and selects 'No', the extra price (which was added) is subtracted from the base price. This is working as it should.

Case 2: When the user clicks 'No' after getting the price, it should keep the price same. What is happening currently is that the extra price is getting subtracted from the base price, IF the user selects 'No' first.

```js
var price = 550;
 var price_container = $('.price_container');

 $('input[type=radio][name=lids_check').change(function() {

   //alert("This works!")
   var lid_price = 50;

   var modifier = (this.value == 'Yes') ? 1 : -1;

   price = parseFloat(price) + (modifier * parseFloat(lid_price));

   console.log(price);
   price_container.html(price);


 });

 $('input[type=radio][name=extras_check').change(function() {

   var extras_price = 200;

   var modifier = (this.value == 'Yes') ? 1 : -1;

   price = parseFloat(price) + (modifier * parseFloat(extras_price));

   console.log(price);
   price_container.html(price);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Base Price</label>
<span>550</span>
<br>
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Lids</label>
<div class="col-sm-4 btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="lids_check" id="lids_checkyes" autocomplete="off" value="Yes"> Yes
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="lids_check" id="lids_checkno" autocomplete="off" value="No"> No
  </label>
</div>
<br>
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Extras</label>
<div class="col-sm-4 btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="extras_check" id="extras_checkyes" autocomplete="off" value="Yes"> Yes
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="extras_check" id="extras_checkno" autocomplete="off" value="No"> No
  </label>
</div>
<br>
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Price</label>
<span class="price_container"></span>
```

Comment: If the user clicks yes twice, would that qualify him to decrement using no twice?  Or, would he still only be allowed to click no once?

Comment: Is "yes" not pre-selected with the extra price added?  If not, can't you do it that way?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The amount has to get added only once regardless if the user clicks yes twice or thrice.

Comment: Right.  If user clicks no.  Total = price.  If user clicks yes, Total = price + extra.  You don't add every time, and there is no need to subtract at all.

Comment: @JeffMatthews, yes exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly, you want to increase the price if yes has not already been selected, and to decrease the price if yes has been selected.  We can implement this logic using a flag variable to keep track of the yes/no choice.

```
var chosen = false;
$('input[type=radio][name=lids_check').change(function() {
    var lid_price = 50;

    if (this.value == 'Yes' && !chosen) {
        price = parseFloat(price) + parseFloat(lid_price);
        chosen = true;
    }
    else if (this.value == 'No' && chosen) {
        price = parseFloat(price) - parseFloat(lid_price);
        chosen = false;
    }

   console.log(price);
   price_container.html(price);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need "modifier."

You are losing track of the item's original price because you recalculate it. You are starting out with price = 550 and ending up with price = some other number.  You can't re-perform the calculation without the original price.

You need to preserve the original price and add to it as needed.  Like this:

```
var originalPrice = 550; <-- don't use the name "price" here.  

...

$('input[type=radio][name=extras_check').change(function() {

   var extras_price = 200;

   price = this.value == 'Yes' ? parseFloat(originalPrice) + parseFloat(extras_price) : parseFloat(originalPrice);

   console.log(price);
   price_container.html(price);
});
```

Comment: If I select 'Yes' , the extra price gets added to the base price but doesn't get subtracted when I select 'No'.

Comment: I edited to refer to the item's original price, assuming it is lid_price.

Comment: The problem before my edit is that before my edit,  price is calculated without reference to the price of the item without extras.  Make sense?

Comment: One more time.  I see lid_price is not your original price.  Check the re-edited answer and see if that makes sense to you.